# Excel vba open folder using same instance of explorer.exe

Tags: excel, vba, explorer

I was using following code in excel vba

```
returnval = Shell("explorer.exe " & folderPath, vbNormalFocus)
```

to open folders, this works fine but it starts a new process of windows explorer. Now 2 windows explorer processes are visible in task manager. If I keep using this function with different `folderPath` it creates a new instance of explorer processes every time.

**How can i use existing explorer.exe instance to open folder from excel vba?**

Comment: When I run the code it doesn't create another instance of explorer.exe

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't happen to you. but i have tried in several win10 machines and clearly see several processes of windows explorer in the task manager. but if i open many folders from outside excel vba they open inside the same process of explorer.exe.

Comment: also if you type "explorer.exe c:\path" in cmd it does the same creating a new process of explorer.exe. but in cmd if typing "start c:\path" won't make a new process. unfortunately if i try replacing "explorer.exe" with "start" in vba code it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of shell, `ThisWorkbook` has follow hyperlink which will open any file/url with the default app. It doesn't open another process of explorer.exe for me.

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\filepath"
```

If you really need to use shell, then you'll have to call cmd.exe then start like this:

```
returnval = Shell("cmd.exe /c start filepath")
```

Comment: this is good, but partially correct. it doesn't create new explorer.exe processes but it create new instances of same folder when executing several times. in the other hand if i use "start c:\folderpath" in cmd while folderpath is already open, it focus back without creating a new window.

Comment: @MaheshUddama I've edited my answer so it uses start

Comment: thanks, 2nd solution does the job, i wasn't intended only to use shell command. but i was explaining to get the effect of start command in cmd. here it flashes the cmd process in the background. are there any other vba approach you know for this? again its not necessary to use shell, start or cmd

Comment: @MaheshUddama unfortunately if you want to if you want to get all of the `functionality` of start you'll have to call it through cmd which will flash up for a short time. So its a trade off between opening a new window each time it's executed or having cmd flash up.

Answer (score 0):

Try full path of explorer.exe . For example you should use C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe instead of explorer.exe. This works for me.

Comment: sorry, its the same effect of original code. if you type "c:\windows\explorer.exe c:\path" in cmd it does the same creating a new process of explorer.exe. but in cmd if typing "start c:\path" won't make a new process. unfortunately if i try replacing "explorer.exe" with "start" in vba code it doesn't work